# Rewriting all request to go to the homepage using Urlrewrite in web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing, urlrewriter.net

I'm trying the following line in my web.config to rewrite all requests that come to my website to go to the home page while converting the the virtual paths to query strings

```
 <rewrite url="~/(.+)$" to="/?pageid=$1"  processing="stop" /
```

I'm always receiving a 404 error that "/" path does not exist.

For example, entering `http://localhost:8082/test/asd` gives a 404 error

```
The resource cannot be found.
Requested URL: /
```

Although going to `http://localhost:8082/` without using urlrewriter works fine and the page displays correctly.

I'm using url rewrite intelligencia (urlrewriter.net)